# adviceDidNotMatch warning and execution stops without giving any error

Tags: aspectj

I'm using aspectj to track state changes in a Java application. Here is my advice:

```
public aspect TrackStateChanges
{
    after( Stateful stateful, StateTracker stateTracker ):
            @annotation(stateful)
                    && target(stateTracker)

                    && !cflow(execution(@PrivilegedAccessor * StateTracker+.*(..)))

                    && (set(@Stateful * StateTracker+.*)
                                || get(@Stateful * StateTracker+.*))

                    && withincode(@StateWriter private * StateTracker+.*(..))
            {
                stateTracker.onStateChanged( stateful.value() );
            }
}
```

And here is my annotation class:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Stateful
{
    ChangedPart value ();
}
```

When I build this, following warning occurs:

> Warning:ajc: advice defined in aspects.TrackStateChanges has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

My imports are solid, I don't think that's a problem. I'm asking because ajc behaves strangely in some cases. Most of the time it works fine, but for specific state fields it doesn't work properly. The problem is it runs `stateTracker.onStateChanged(stateful.value())` and then execution stops, thread is killed after executing `finally` block. I don't get any exception or nothing. Is this problem related with the warning? Or something else?

I'm using aspectj-maven-plugin v1.6 and aspectjrt v1.7.3

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit like a stackoverflow case where the advice invokes something that eventually loops back to the advice. The stack overflow is being swallowed rather than printed. But that is somewhat contradictory to the adviceDidNotMatch message. I would only expect that message if you are compiling in two stages:

(1) Compile just the aspects without the targets of the aspects being compiled in the same step

(2) Compile the target code, applying the aspects.

At step (1) you will get adviceDidNotMatch because the target code isn't around.

You could confirm if it is a stack overflow by commenting out just the advice body, or replace it with a `System.out.println("in advice!")`. If that works and doesn't lock up you could try printing the stack in the advice, that may show you what is leading to the overflow. So change the advice body to something like `Thread.currentThread().dumpStack()` (that may print a lot!).

If it is this problem, you could introduce a clause `!cflow(adviceexecution())` which will prevent advice triggering because of advice.

Although if that helps then perhaps it is a problem with the `!cflow` - to implement something like `!cflow(execution(...))` AspectJ will need to be able to see all the `...` places in order to mark them. If AspectJ was not able to instrument all those places then the cflow check will fail and the advice will be run even though the condition you expressed is not met. AspectJ wouldn't be able to instrument all the places if it wasn't being given all the code to weave. If you were referring to code on a classpath for example, rather than an inpath or compiling the source for those cflow() pointcut targets with ajc.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I discovered the problem and it has nothing to do with aspectj, my bad. But I still get the warning, is there any problem with my advice or is it about compiling as you said?

Comment: If the compile is happening separately (aspects up front before being applied to the main code), the warning is totally expected. IIRC you can add a `@SuppressAjWarnings` for adviceDidNotMatch on the advice to avoid the warning if you want to remove it.  If you are building all your source together (including the aspect) and still get this, then there is something wrong with your pointcut. In that case break it down into pieces and see which is causing it not to match.